# Category of Multisets and Spans

Tags: category-theory, multisets

I have been thinking about multisets for a while.  These are sets where elements can repeat, so $S =\{ a,a,b,c,b\}$ is a multiset on the set $A = \{a,b,c\}$.

I have also been looking into morphisms between multisets.  Take two multisets $S_A, S_B$ with underlying sets $A, B$.  I would like to define a morphism between multisets $S_A, S_B$ as a span on the underlying sets, so $f = A \leftarrow C \rightarrow B$, and $f: S_A \rightarrow S_B$.

Here is how I am defining the morphisms.  Take a multiset $S_A$ and let $a_i$ be one of the terms, likewise for $S_B$ and $b_j$.  We have an indexing set $C$ and let the $f, g$ be arms of a span so $f: C \rightarrow A$ and $g: C \rightarrow B$.  Let $c_i \in C$ and let $f(c_i)$ be the set element of term $a_i$, likewise for $g(c_j)$.

I am not sure how to define span composition.  I want a category of multisets with morphisms as defined.  Does there exist a composition that gives such a category?  I realize there are many options for defining the composition, and I really don't know which one I want.  Is there a body of work that focuses on what all the different choices of composition mean for this particular problem?

Does my definition of the objects and morphisms define a category?

Comment: Your definition of the morphisms is bizarre: you're saying that $S_A$ and $S_B$ don't matter at all for defining a morphism $S_A\to S_B$, only the sets $A$ and $B$ matter??

Comment: @EricWofsey Hi, I tried to give my intuition on how the morphisms work.  It is based on the idea that you can describe a vector via a span between basis elements and the field, or semiring multiplier.